# cython: how to declare a cdef function that has no return

Tags: cython

when I declare a cdef function that returns a double I write `cdef double method_name(...)`. If it does not return something and I just omit it to `cdef method_name(...)` then cython --annotate marks it yellow. How to declare that the method/function does not return anything?

`cdef void method_name(...)` crashes with a segmentation fault

`cdef None method_name(...)` -> `'None' is not a type identifier`

Comment: can you provide an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the exact error you get? Oh, and probably also your cython version, just in case.

Comment: Thanks: that was the problem a bug in Cython version 0.22. Update to 0.23.4 solved it.

Answer (score 3):

`--annotate` marks it as yellow as cython assumes the return type to be a python object if you omit the return type annotation ([Cython Language Basics](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html)).

Specifying void as return type *works for me*. It's also used in quite some of the official examples, Just make sure not to return anything.

Answer (score 2):

For me (cython 0.21.1) defining the c function with `void` works:

```
# mymod.pyx file

cdef void mycfunc(int* a):
    a[0] = 2

def myfunc():
    cdef int a = 1
    mycfunc(&a)
    print(a)
```

The c function is not yellow in the annotated html file and

```
python -c 'from mymod import myfunc; myfunc()'
```

prints `2` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A bug in Cython version 0.22. Update to 0.23.4 solved it.